# $http.delete not working inside foreach

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to delete rows from a grid. Inside a foreach function I need to make $http.delete call to delete from database. Below is the code I wrote with help from another similar question. Please advise whats wrong. It reaches upto $http.delete but doesnt make the call.

```
var promises = [];

angular.forEach($scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows(),
  function (data, index) 
  { $scope.gridOptions.data.splice($scope.gridOptions.data.lastIndexOf(data), 1);
    promises.push($scope.deleteRow(data._id));            
  }
); 

$q.all(promises).then(
function success(){alert("Delete successful");},
function failure(err){alert("Error in deletion");}
);

$scope.deleteRow = function(rowId)
{
    return $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/deleterecords/' + data._id);
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Any code snippet you can provide with?

Comment: Did you look for errors in the Javascript console of the browser developer tools?

Comment: Thanks Johannes !.. Am new to javascript debugging, yes as you suggested I checked the browser developer tools and there was the error in console tab...as squaleLis suggested below, reference error for data variable !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `deleteRow` function you have no access more to `data`.
You should change your code to:

```
$scope.deleteRow = function(rowId) {
    return $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/deleterecords/' + rowId);
}
```

Comment: Sure, i was just waiting to test to confirm nothing else is broken :)...here you go !